# Why do the English say ''Harvard University'' or ''Manchester Airport'' but ''the Guggenheim Museum''?

Tags: grammar, articles

My question is why do the English say "Harvard University" or "Manchester Airport" but "the Guggenheim Museum".

According to the book *English grammar in use* — the blue one — when the first word is a name of a place or a person we don't use "the" but why do we say "the Guggenheim" despite the fact that it's a surname?

PS: I'm not so sure if it's OK to share a screenshot of the related page but it's on page 156. unit 78.

Comment: @orhan Is *English Grammar in Use* by [Raymond Murphy](https://www.google.com/search?q=english+grammar+in+use)? If so, please edit that in, together with the edition/year of publication. Rather than a screenshot, please type out the relevant bit and use `>` to indicate a quote.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133882/discussion-on-question-by-orhan-torun-why-do-the-english-say-harvard-universit).

Answer (score 1):

It's idiomatic. *Museum* carries different expectations around the article compared to, say, *university*.

For example, when using university names of the form `X University`, the article is usually omitted. For instance, the set of Ivy League universities follows this convention:

> Harvard University
>
> Brown University
>
> Columbia University
>
> Cornell University
>
> Princeton University
>
> Yale University

One might refer to an object or entity associated with the university using an article (*[The Harvard University Register](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Harvard_University_Register/-PcTAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0),* *[The Harvard University Band](https://www.harvardband.org/)*), but it would be immediately conspicuous to say *the Harvard University* and not follow up with another noun phrase (even common ones like *crew team* or *grounds*). It's idiomatic.

Museums are different. Museums very often carry an article in their title when called `X Museum`. For instance, and off the top of my head:

> [The Victoria and Albert Museum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victoria_and_Albert_Museum) (or *the V&A*)
>
> [The Metropolitan Museum of Art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolitan_Museum_of_Art) (or *the Met*)
>
> [The J. Paul Getty Museum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._Paul_Getty_Museum) (or *the Getty*)
>
> [The British Museum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Museum)

In other words, *museum* has a stronger tendency to adopt the article *the* even when headed by a name. This is also idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

A university or college is a collection of facilities & dorms, making it seem like a “place”, like a city. (“We went to Chicago.”) A museum is typically a single structure, like any other building. (“We went to the Carnegie Library.”)

Comment: Although we say "The University of XXX".